# Why is $\langle 0| \phi (x) \phi (y) |0 \rangle = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{2E_p} e^{-i p (x-y)}$ ? (Peskin and Schroeder equation 2.50)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, propagator

More specifically, starting from $\langle 0| \phi (x) \phi (y) |0 \rangle$  I have arrived at the expression:

$D(x-y)=\langle 0| \phi (x) \phi (y) |0 \rangle= {\Large\int \int} \frac{d^3p \cdot d^3q}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_q} \delta^{(3)}( \vec p - \vec q) e^{i(q \cdot y -p \cdot x)}={\Large\int \int} \frac{d^3p \cdot d^3q}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_q} \delta^{(3)}( \vec p - \vec q) e^{i(q_0y^0 - \vec q \cdot \vec y -p_0x^0+ \vec p \cdot \vec x)}=   {\Large\int } \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_p} e^{i(q_0y^0  -p_0x^0+ \vec p \cdot (\vec x - \vec y))}$

However, I should be getting ${ \Large\int} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{2E_p} e^{-i p (x-y)}$

I don't understand why, since the delta function is 3D and thus does not act on $q_0$ to change it into $p_0$ (which would result in Peskin's formula). What am I missing?

Comment: For anyone who may stumble upon this in the future, I _think_ I've found the solution quickly after posting this. When plugging in the expressions for  $\phi (x)$ and $\phi (y)$ at the start, I used p and q to represent different variables of integration, (which are $p^1, p^2, p^3$ and $q^1, q^2, q^3$), however I also used different variable names for $p^0$ and $q^0$. This is incorrect, since I am only integrating over $p^1, p^2$ and $p^3$, NOT over $p^0$

Comment: When you expand the field in creation and annihilation operators all momenta are on the mass-shell. This means $p^0$ *is not* independent from $\mathbf p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p_0$ and $q_0$ are functions of $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$. Namely ($m$ is the mass of the particle):

$p_0 = \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2 +m^2} \quad\quad \text{and} \quad \quad q_0 = \sqrt{\mathbf{q}^2 +m^2}$

(This is not valid for virtual particles however). Therefore when the $\delta$-function is applied $q_0\rightarrow p_0$, so the problem is solved.

**Background** : The motion of a free particle is governed by a dispersion relation, for a Schroedinger particle it is $E = \frac{(\hbar \mathbf{k})^2}{2m} = \frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m}$, ($\mathbf{k}$ is the wave vector) for a photon it is $E^2=\mathbf{p}^2$, and for a relativistic scalar particle (and other types of particles) $E^2=\mathbf{p}^2 +m^2$
(speed of light  $c$ set to 1).